# Errno 13 - Permission Denied trying to access USB using LIBUSB (Windows)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python script for a NFC Read / Write tool, specifically the ACR122U on Windows 11 utilising the `nfcpy` library. Whenever I run this code.

```
import nfc

clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend()
assert clf.open('usb:002:010') is True
```

I get `[Errno 13] Permission denied usb1.USBErrorAccess: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS [-3]`

Similarly, running `python -m nfc` it gets `** found usb:072f:2200 at usb:002:010 but access is denied`

I've run VS Code as administrator, I've made sure this full modify for permissions on the user. I am the admin user, I don't know what else privileges I can give to myself that could allow my code to access the USB.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user running the script has the necessary permissions to access the USB device. You can check the permissions on the USB device in the Device Manager:

1. Open Device Manager.
2. Find your ACR122U device under "Universal Serial Bus controllers."
3. Right-click on it, go to "Properties," and navigate to the "Security" tab.
4. Ensure that your user account has the necessary permissions.